# Multiple params with React Router change url but not component

Tags: reactjs, routes

I want after clicking on link-button it redirects me to another page with full url, like -> localhost:3001/companies/name/forms

But it does not redirect anywhere, only change url each time I click .. like -> localhost:3001/companies/name/name/name/forms

```
<BrowserRouter>
...
<Switch>
  ...
  <Route path='/companies' exact component={CompanyList}></Route>
  <Route 
     path='/companies/:slug' 
     render={(props) => <CompanyDetails {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
   />
  <Route path='companies/:slug/forms' exact component={Forms}></Route>
<Switch>
...
</BrowserRouter>
```

And link to the path from CompanyDetails page(component)

```
<Button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary">
      <Link to={`${this.props.match.params.slug}/forms`}>
         Create&nbsp; 
         <i className="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </Link>
</Button>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rearrange the order of your route and also add `exact`

also in your code path='companies/:slug/forms' is missing a `/`

```
<Route exact path='/companies/:slug/forms' exact component={Forms}></Route>      
<Route 
  exact
  path='/companies/:slug' 
  render={(props) => <CompanyDetails {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
/>
```

If above doesn't work, try add `/` to your link in CompanyDetails page

```
<Link to={`/${this.props.match.params.slug}/forms`}>
```

Comment: You have a missing `/` in your path='companies/:slug/forms'

Comment: did you try the `exact` also?

Comment: Thanks cYee, it helps to redirect to another page ... but not component. Any idea?

Comment: For sure, do you mean the link changed but the component is not rendered?